# MySQL query with GROUP BY and subquery with ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of messages, each belonging to a unique conversation (conversation_id). I want to select the latest message from each conversation.

The query below works, however it seems very inefficient since the sub query is selecting all messages sent to the user.

```
SELECT
    conversation_id,
    to_id,
    from_id,
    time_sent,
    type,
    message
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        messages
    WHERE
        to_id = :uid
    OR
        from_id = :uid
    ORDER BY
        time_sent
    DESC
)
AS
    t1
GROUP BY
    conversation_id
ORDER BY
    time_sent
DESC
```

If I only include a `GROUP BY` it selects the first (oldest) rows:

```
SELECT
    conversation_id,
    to_id,
    from_id,
    time_sent,
    type,
    message
FROM
    messages
WHERE
    to_id = :uid
OR
    from_id = :uid
GROUP BY
    conversation_id
```

But when I do `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` in the same query, it returns the first (oldest) rows from each conversation, not the last, so the `ORDER BY` isn't working or not doing what I expected.

```
SELECT
    conversation_id,
    to_id,
    from_id,
    time_sent,
    type,
    message
FROM
    messages
WHERE
    to_id = :uid
OR
    from_id = :uid
GROUP BY
    conversation_id
ORDER BY
    time_sent
DESC
```

I'm pretty sure I need the sub query, but how can I do it without selecting all messages first?

Comment: There is rarely, if ever, a situation where an order by clause inside a subquery makes any sense.  If you think you need a subquery, include one, but only use an order by clause in your main query.

Comment: To be honest.. I don't understand why you need a sub query here?

Comment: Because in MySQL, GROUP BY and ORDER BY don't work together in the same query. At least that's what I've found out from all my Google searches.

Comment: @Gavin What are you doing where `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` don't work together? Do you have a reproducible sample? Could you SQLFiddle it?

Comment: I didn't even know SQLFiddle existed :) I think rohitr figured it out though.

Comment: Your 2nd bit of sql does not select the first (oldest) rows. If select an undefined row for the other values for a conversation_id. This might be the oldest row (and is normally), but is not certain to be. It is GROUP BY that doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to join this table with a subquery with `conversation_id` and max(time_sent) for each conversation:

```
SELECT
    m.conversation_id,
    m.to_id,
    m.from_id,
    m.time_sent,
    m.type,
    m.message
FROM messages as m
JOIN 
   (SELECT  conversation_id,
            MAX(time_sent) as MAX_time_sent
    FROM  messages
    WHERE to_id = :uid  OR from_id = :uid
    GROUP BY conversation_id
   ) AS t1
   ON m.conversation_id=t1.conversation_id AND m.time_sent = t1.MAX_time_sent

ORDER BY m.time_sent DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great and you had the correct answer first.

Answer (score 2):

This might be the way you are looking for

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE conversation_id = (
 SELECT id
 FROM conversations
 WHERE id={insert id here...}
 LIMIT 0,1)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I assumed you select by conversation id.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it (assuming that the to_id and from_id are consistent for a conversation):-

```
SELECT messages.conversation_id,
    messages.to_id,
    messages.from_id,
    messages.time_sent,
    messages.type,
    messages.message
FROM 
(
    SELECT conversation_id, MAX(time_sent) AS max_time_sent
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY conversation_id
) t1
INNER JOIN messages
ON t1.conversation_id = messages.conversation_id
AND t1.max_time_sent = messages.time_sent
WHERE messages.to_id = :uid
OR messages.from_id = :uid
```

Comment: This worked, but I just had to add `ORDER BY time_sent DESC` to the very end (the times are timestamps)

Comment: Aye, they were a few seconds ahead of me I think. Only real difference is that their solution put the checks for the uid in the sub query while I put it outside the sub query

Comment: Yep, I'm thinking that may improve the speed a fraction of a fraction of a second, since it's returning a smaller result set, right?

Comment: Maybe, but also it forces it to process the full messages table on the join rather than a sub set of that table (depending on indexes).

Comment: You could which might well be the most efficient

Comment: I'll do that then. Thank you so much for your advice. Really appreciate it.